# FFMPEG command works in shell ! but not in my node.js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

When my ffmpeg command is built by my node.js application it does not run.

error

```
Unrecognized option 'ss 3.2 -t 1.9 -i videoplayback.mp4 -vf  fps=15,scale=240:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png'.
```

command

```
ffmpeg -ss 3.2 -t 1.9 -i videoplayback.mp4 -vf \ fps=15,scale=240:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
```

this is my code

```
var child_process = require('child_process')

function recordVideo() {

var spawn = child_process.spawn;

var args = [
    '-y', 
    '-ss', '3.2',
    '-t', '1.9', 
    '-i', '../getback/bin/videos/videoplayback.mp4', 
    '-vf', ' \\ ', 
    'fps=', '15', 
    'scale=', '320:-1', 
    'flags=','lanczos,palettegen palette.png', 
];



var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('grep stderr: ' + data);
});

ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
}); 
};
recordVideo();
```

what is this error?
I think.. **'fps=', '15',** In the following code 
 '=' options a problem.

I am still learning English.
I'm sorry if it was hard to understand.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node will put a space between every argument in the array you give to child_process.spawn function, as the second argument, when it's building your command. Try replacing the argument pairs like "fps=" and "15" with a single argument: "fps=15".

Comment: humm. i  got the following error `[NULL @ 0x3b35b40] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fps = 15'
fps = 15: Invalid argument` this is my code `'fps = 15', 'scale = 320:-1',  `

Comment: i Solved it!! `    var args = [
       '-ss','3.2',
       '-t','1.9',
       '-i',`${mp4path}`,
       '-vf','fps=15,scale=240:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen',`${output}`
    ];`

Comment: Great! I'm glad to read that. Notice the "invalid argument" you were getting was probably because the string "fps = 15" contained two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference one can view the spawned arguments by reading the [spawnargs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_spawnargs) property from the created child process.